# Formula manipulation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, formula

I am wanting to make a program that will when given a formula, it can manipulate the formula to make any value (or in the case of a simultaneous formula, a common value) the subject of the formula.

For example if given:

```
a + b = c
d + b = c
```

The program should therefore say:

```
b = c - a, d = c - b    etc.
```

I'm not sure if java can do this automatically or not when I give the original formula as input. I am not really interested in solving the equation and getting the result of each variable, I am just interested in returning a manipulated formula.

Please let me know if I need to make an algorithm or not for this, and if so, how would I go about doing this. Also, if there are any helpful links that you might have, please post them.

Regards

Comment: The only thing available is string manipulation, and you would have to write it yourself. Have fun...

Comment: Java has no builtin for this. You would need at least a parser and a symbolic processor for that... Maybe have a look at parboiled, it is actually fun to write grammars with it (unlike JavaCC or AntLR).

Comment: Thanks, I look forward to the challenge. So, I should have each formula as a string, manipulate it and then convert them into integers, doubles etc. ?

Comment: Will have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Digitalwolf oh, I thought you really wanted symbolic processing, not actual calculations. In this case it is even more simple: parboiled has a ready-to-use calculator :p

Comment: I feel obligated to point this out in the chance you aren't familiar with it: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC). It's a little daunting at first but it's the right tool for something like this. Plus there are already [examples](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~vick/431/Lectures/Spring06/3_LexicalAnalysis/3_Tools/2_JavaCC_Example.htm) of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please elaborate how one should use javaCC to achieve what he is after. He is looking to create new formulas from the given formula, parsing it (which can indeed be easily done by javaCC) is only the smallest issue here

Answer (score 1):

I read a book called `Fluid Concepts and Creative Analogies` by Douglas Hofstadter that talked about this sort of algebraic manipulations that would automatically rewrite equations in other ways attempting to join equations to other equations an infinite (yet restricted) number of ways given rules.  It was an attempt to prove yet unproven theorems/proofs by brute force.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_Concepts_and_Creative_Analogies

Douglas Hofstadter's Numbo program attempts to do what you want.  He doesn't give you the source, only describes how it works in detail.

It sounds like you want a program to do what highschool students do when they solve algebraic problems to move from a position where you know something, modifying it and combining it with other equations, to prove something previously unknown.  It takes a strong Artificial intelligence to do this.  The part of your brain that does this is the Neo Cortex, which does science, and it's operating principle is as of yet not understood.

If you want something that will do what college students do when they manipulate equations in calculus, you'll have to build a fairly strong artificial intelligence.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neocortex

When we can do whole-brain emulation of a human neo cortex, I will post the answer here.

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what my end goal is. Will try and get a hold of this book.

Comment: Good sir you've picked some of the hardest problems in computer science, good on you.  Also this course will help give you the tools for the job: https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/preview

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are after, but this problem in its general problem is hard. Very hard.

In fact, given a set of "formulas" (axioms), and deduction rules (mathematical equivalence operations), **we cannot deduce if a given formula is correct or not**. This problem is actually [*undecideable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).

This issue was first addressed by Hilbert as [Entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to write some algorithm to do this kind of computer algebra. At least

- a parser to interpret the input
- an algebra model to relate parsed operands ('a', 'b', ...) and operator ('+', '=')
- implement any appropriate rule to support the manipulation you wish to do

Comment: Already have all of that set up. just need the appropriate rule for the manipulation. A few other posts have brought so very valid points to my attention. Thanks